# Escape Special characters in Cakephp find query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

Using

> **Cakephp version: 2.5.1**

I have some trouble finding a solution for dealing special characters in Cakephp find queries.
If you could please point me in right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Here is the piece of code. This code fetches all records from Titles table where the name meets certain conditions

```
public function findTitles($text) {
    return $this->find('all', 
        array(
            'fields' => array('id', 'name'),
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                    array('name LIKE ' => $text.'%'),
                    array('name LIKE ' => '% '.$text.'%')
                    ),
                'original' => 1
                ),
            'order' => array('id ASC'),
            'limit' => 10
            )
        );
}
```

So if my `$text = "pro"` for example i.e `?q=pro`, below is the Mysql equivalent query that is generated

```
SELECT `Title`.`id`, `Title`.`name` FROM `database`.`titles` WHERE ((`name` LIKE 'pro%') OR (`name` LIKE '% pro%')) AND `original` = 1  ORDER BY `id` ASC  LIMIT 10
```

Now if my $text = "%", i.e `?q=%`, then below is the query generated

```
SELECT `Title`.`id`, `Title`.`name` FROM `database`.`titles` WHERE ((`name` LIKE '%%') OR (`name` LIKE '% %%')) AND `original` = 1   ORDER BY `id` ASC  LIMIT 10
```

In this case I get the first 10 records from table. What I want is fetch first 10 records that has the symbol '%' in it. But rather, CakePHP does not escape it.

So I tried putting this line of code in my function:

```
$text = str_replace('%',  '\%',  $text);
```

As like this

```
public function findTitles($text) {
    $text = str_replace('%',  '\%',  $text);
    return $this->find('all', ................
```

Then I get the below mysql query

```
SELECT `Title`.`id`, `Title`.`name` FROM `database`.`titles` WHERE ((`name` LIKE '\\%%') OR (`name` LIKE '% \\%%')) AND `original` = 1   ORDER BY `id` ASC  LIMIT 10
```

In this, the backslash is then also escaped by another backslash. Which i think is incorrect, as we need to escape only '%'

Any solutions will be surely appreciated. If I am missing any information, or any more explanation if required, please let me know. I will update in comments.

Comment: Please always mention the exact CakePHP version that you are using!

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question. CakePHP version 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use regular expression to remove all special characters from your string.

**Remove all special characters**

```
public function findTitles($text) {
    $pattern  = '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/';  #Only allowed numbers and characters
    #$pattern = '/[^A-Za-z\-]/';     #Only allowed characters
    $text     = preg_replace($pattern '', $text);

    /*YOUR CODE HERE*/

}
```

After replacing the special characters, You no need to change your Query